# Different complex pairs giving same magnitude and phase

Tags: phase, complex, magnitude

I am trying to fit data of magnitude and phase to get complex pairs(for FFT), but I think it would be a wrong approach as different pairs of complex numbers can give same amplitude and phase , is my assumption correct? is there some obvious example for this assumption through which I can prove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To one magnitude and phase corresponds only exactly one complex number.  The ambiguity accurs in the other direction: for 0+0i, the phase is arbitrary, for other numbers, the phase is ambiguous because adding multiples of 2pi to it gives the same complex number.

But different complex pairs can never give the same magnitude and phase.